# Putting a file encoded with UTF-8 on the clipboard with CLIP.EXE under Windows?

Tags: windows, clipboard, unicode

I have a situation where I have a Java program that first write a text file and then invokes "CMD /C CLIP < textfile" to be able to put an arbitrarily large file on the Windows clipboard.  Works well.

Now I've found that there is an encoding issue so I have ensured I have a valid UTF-8 encoded file (including the BOM, and it opens correctly in vim) but it appears that CLIP.EXE does not honor the BOM to change the expected encoding to UTF-8.

So, how should I tell Windows and/or CLIP.EXE that this file is UTF-8 encoded and treat it accordingly?  (If another encoding like UTF-16 or UTF-32 would work better for Unicode I can use that instead).

The system showing the behavior is Windows 7 and the default codepage in CMD.EXE is 850.  I need this to work on systems I do not have any control over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-16 works for me, on my Windows 7 (my OEM ('cmd') codepage is 437, though it shouldn't matter).

How I tested:

1. Open notepad, type some non-ASCII texts (or copy from some site with many langs, like http://wikipedia.org
2. Save As, choose Encoding: Unicode (which means UTF-16), save as UTF16.txt
3. In cmd, type `clip < UTF16.txt`
4. Open new notepad, paste

Result: Text appears correctly.

Comment: It turned out that the UTF_16LE Java encoding (with an explicit BOM) works as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using vim instead of notepad, you might need to explicitly set the UTF-16 encoding upon writing the file: `:w ++enc=utf16-le filename.txt`

Comment: Small caveat: `clip.exe` actually _includes the BOM_ in what it copies to the clipboard. This may or may not be a problem, depending on how the data is used, but to be safe, use UTF16-LE input _without_ a BOM.

Comment: Correction on Vim command from the comment above: at least in Vim 9, the encoding is called `utf-16le`, not `utf16-le` (see `:help encoding-values`).